# Wget Specify Sub directories to Download (-I)

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, wget

I have just started using `wget` and am able to download and specify location to save files in, but I am having issues when I try to limit my download to portions of the main directory.  If I do not include anything trying to limit the directory, everything works fine and I get all of the documents but cannot get the `-I` function to work correctly.

`wget -r -nd -A pdf -I /002-60N87,/007-61E84,/008-61E85,/009-61E89,/010-61E90,/065-61E29,/PA061-10A http://apps.dot.st.gov/ep/de/080318/ -P M:/TEMPORARY/WGET/`

I am having issues figuring out what I am doing incorrectly.  Does anyone see a problem with what I am doing or able to provide any guidance?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Do you receive any error messages when using the `-I` flag? Or is the output just unexpected?

Comment: I do not receive any error messages, just unexpected output.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is whether or not `wget` is appending the included directories list directly onto the URL you are trying to retrieve creating a double // scenario, e.g. http://apps.dot.st.gov/ep/de/080318//002-60N87

Comment: Perhaps try running the command with `-v` to enable verbose mode to see what it's doing at step?

Comment: I ran with the -v command and I do not know enough about wget to know what should be written here.  Do not know if this matters, but if I run with -nd then I see no changes, but if I remove this command the folder structure downloads all the way to 080318 level, but none of the sub directories.

Comment: I also edited the command deleting the -I command and references to subdirectories and instead included reference to a single subdirectory by adding it to the address.  Doing this I am able getting the documents that I would expect.  Problem is something to do with my -I command and/or how I am referencing the subdirectories